# AuthProvider operation fails for React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, firebase-authentication

I'm doing user login checks using the AuthProvider method. When I enter the correct information on the login screen, I encounter an error as follows.

> Login Screen

```
 import React, { useState, useContext } from "react";
import * as Yup from "yup";
import { Formik } from "formik";
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';
import LinearGradient from 'react-native-linear-gradient';
import Color from 'react-native-material-color';
import { AuthContext } from '../../Navigation/AuthProvider';
import {
Text,
View,
StyleSheet,
SafeAreaView,
Image,
TextInput,
Button,
ScrollView,
TouchableOpacity
} from 'react-native';







export default login = ({navigation})=>{

  const { useContext } = React;
  const {login} = useContext(AuthContext);

  const signInvalidationSchema =Yup.object().shape({

    email:Yup
    .string()
    .required('boş geçilemez')
    .email('geçerli bir email adresi yaziniz'),
    
    password:Yup
    .string()
    .required('boş geçilemez').min(6,({min})=>'sifre en az '+ min +'karakter olmalıdır!')
    })
  /*function _handleSubmit (values){

    auth()
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(values.email, values.password)
      .then(() => {
        alert('basarılı giriş')
      })
      .catch(error => {
        if (error.code === 'auth/wrong-password') {
          alert('wrong pass')
          return;
        }
        if (error.code === 'auth/user-not-found') {
          alert('User Not Found');
          return;
        }
        console.error(error);
      });
    this.props.navigation.navigate('profile');
  }*/

    return (

      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <ScrollView>
          <View style={styles.top}>
            <Image
              style={{
                width: 150,
                height: 200,
                resizeMode: 'contain'
              }}
              source={
                require('../../image/logo.png')
              }
            />
            <Text style={styles.textLogo}>AGER FORUM</Text>
          </View>
          <Formik
            initialValues={{
              email: '',
              password: ''
            }}
            onSubmit={(values)=>login(values.email,values.password)}
            validationSchema={signInvalidationSchema}
          >
            {
              ({
                values,
                handleSubmit,
                isValid,
                isSubmitting,
                errors,
                handleBlur,
                handleChange
              }) => (

                <View style={styles.mid}>
                  <View style={styles.box}>
                    <View style={styles.textBox}>
                      <Text style={styles.textMid}>E-mail</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.inputView}>
                      <LinearGradient
                        colors={['#840ec1', '#a643d9', '#d743d9', '#be1dc0', '#a00ba2', '#8a04a6']}
                        start={{ x: 0.0, y: 1.0 }} end={{ x: 1.0, y: 1.0 }}
                        style={styles.grediant}
                      >

                        <TextInput
                          values={values.email}
                          onChangeText={handleChange('email')}
                          onBlur={handleBlur('email')}
                          placeholder={"Email"}
                          placeholderTextColor={"#302000"}
                          style={styles.input}
                          keyboardType="email-address"

                        />
                        
                      </LinearGradient>
                      {(errors.email) && <Text style={styles.error}>{errors.email}</Text>}
                    </View>

                    {/*(errors.email) && <Text styles={styles.error}>{errors.email}</Text>*/}
                  </View>
                  <View style={styles.box}>
                    <View style={styles.textBox}>
                      <Text style={styles.textMid}>Şifre</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.inputView}>
                      <LinearGradient
                        colors={['#840ec1', '#a643d9', '#d743d9', '#be1dc0', '#a00ba2', '#8a04a6']}
                        start={{ x: 0.0, y: 1.0 }} end={{ x: 1.0, y: 1.0 }}
                        style={styles.grediant}
                      >
                        <TextInput

                          values={values.password}
                          onChangeText={handleChange('password')}
                          onBlur={handleBlur('password')}
                          placeholder={"Password"}
                          placeholderTextColor={"#302000"}
                          style={styles.input}
                          secureTextEntry={true}

                        />
                       
                      </LinearGradient>
                      {(errors.password) && <Text style={styles.error}>{errors.password}</Text>}
                    </View>
                  </View>
                  <TouchableOpacity
                    disabled={!isValid }
                    onPress={handleSubmit}
                    style={styles.button}
                  >
                    <Text style={styles.button_text}>Sign in My Account</Text>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                  <View style={styles.kayitText}>
                    <TouchableOpacity
                      onPress={() =>navigation.navigate('Register')}

                    >
                      <Text style={{ color: 'white', fontSize: 14, fontWeight: 'bold' }}>Kayit Ol</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                  </View>
                </View>
              )
            }
          </Formik>
          <View style={styles.bot}>

          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </SafeAreaView>

    );
  
}
```

> AuthProvider Code

```
    import { View, Text } from 'react-native'
import React,{useState,useEffect,createContext} from 'react'
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth'



export const AuthContext = createContext({}); 

export const AuthProvider = ({children}) => {
    console.log('first');
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
    
  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
    
    value={{
        user,
        setUser,
        login:async(email,password)=>{
            try {
                await auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
                .then(async result =>{
                    if(!result.user.emailVerified){
                        result.user.sendEmailVerification();
                        alert('Lütfen emailinize gelen maili onaylayınız')
                    }
                })
            } catch (error) {
                console.log('errorlogin',error),
                console.log('user',user)
            }
        },

        register:async(email,password,name)=>{
            try {
                await auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
                .then(async result =>{

                    result.user.updateProfile({
                        displayName:name
                    })
                        result.user.sendEmailVerification();
                        alert('Kayıt işlemi bittikten sonra lütfen emailinize gelen maili onaylayınız')
                    
                })
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error),
                console.log('user',user)
            }
        },

        resetPass:async(email)=>{
            try {
                await auth().sendPasswordResetEmail(email);
                alert('sifre sıfırlama kodunuz emaile gönderilmiştir')
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error)
            }
        },

        signOut:async()=>{
            try {
                await auth().signOut();
                alert('çıkış başarılı')
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error)
            }
        },

    }}

    >{children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

> Fault

[image]

I know this is just a warning but although everything looks correct it doesn't complete successfully and I don't get an error either

Answer (score 0):

@TURAN BİCAV
This is a TypeError. Because you didn't define the type for your AuthContext.
Please check [this document](https://react-typescript-cheatsheet.netlify.app/docs/basic/getting-started/context/#basic-example).

Comment: Can you show me exactly how I can do it through the code?

Comment: @TURAN Did you read the documentation?

Comment: `interface AppContextInterface {
  login: (email:string, password:string) => void;
}

const AppCtx = createContext<AppContextInterface | null>(null);`

Comment: I looked but I didn't understand how to do it on my code, can you edit it on my code?